# How to log a bad request with Soap in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, log4j, soapui

I am trying to log a bad soap request.

I tried: log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing=TRACE

That seems to work find for valid requests and responses, but once the request is bad, nothing get split out in the log. Is there a way to see whats wrong with the request?

Comment: TRACE is a fine grained meaning it should give for bad request as well

Comment: @PrabinPaudel No the soap message is not being created, because it is invalid XLM.  I would just like to know what wrong with the XML.